# acf/validate_value, error sent to an other windows than acf_form's one

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

ACF 6.0.7, PHP 7.4.26, Apache 2.4.51

I have created custom post type entreprise and employe.

When I create a employe for a entreprise, I search if the employe doesn't already exist. I do that:

```
add_filter('acf/validate_value/name=nomprenoms', 'existenceEmploye',10,4);

function existenceEmploye( $valid, $value, $field, $input_name ) {


$entreprise=$_GET['ent'];

  if ( !$value) {
      return __( "employee name is mandatory" );  
  }


$nomPrenoms=explode(",",$value);

if (strlen($nomPrenoms[0]) ==0 || 
    strlen($nomPrenoms[0]) == strlen($value) ||
    strlen($nomPrenoms[0]) == strlen($value) -1 ) {
  return __( "La syntaxe est nom, prenoms" ); 
}


$args = array(
'posts_per_page'    => -1,
'post_type'         => 'employe',
'meta_query'      => array (
  'relation'      =>'AND',
  array (
    'key'         =>'nomprenoms',
    'value'       =>$value,
    'compare'     =>'=',
     ),
array (
    'key'         =>'entreprise',
    'value'       =>$entreprise,
    'compare'     =>'=',
     ),
  ),

);

// var_dump($args);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );


if (count($the_query->posts)) {  
        wp_reset_postdata(); 
        return ( "The employee exits already" );  
    }
else {
          wp_reset_postdata(); 
}


  return $valid;
    
}
```

I expected that the error message appears above ACF Fields. In fact, ACF fields disappear.
The window is :
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYNKw.png)
I have a Internal Server Error 500

If the name is not present or if it has not a good format the error message is displayed above ACF Fields.
Thanks for your help

Comment: put this code in config.php file=> ini_set('display_errors','Off'); ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL ); define('WP_DEBUG', true); define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true); define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true ); and check in wp-content folder debug file , you can find where the exact problem was!

Comment: Thanks a lot, I saw my error,  $_GET['ent'] doesn't return anything whereas 'ent'  is in the Url. I found 'entreprise' because I put it in a ACF_Field and I used $entreprise=$_POST['acf'] ['field_63b7f8f0e992c'];

Comment: I am glad it works for you. Please, could you label this post as the "right answer" and vote it up if it was useful for you. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put this code in config.php file=> ini_set('display_errors','Off'); ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL ); define('WP_DEBUG', true); define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true); define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true ); and check in wp-content folder debug file , you can find where the exact problem was!